# MediaWikiで作成記事が文字化けする

Tags: php, mysql, api

MediaWikiで新しい記事を作成する際に、記事の本文が文字化けして表示されます。
タイトル文章は正しく表示され、MySQLにも日本語で保存されていることは確認しました。
また、ブラウザの設定よりJavascriptを切って記事の編集を行いましたが文字化けは解消されませんでした。
現在の環境は以下のとおりです。
OS:CnetOS6.8
DB:mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
※使用する文字コードの設定はUTF-8
PHP:5.6.27
MediaWiki:1.27
ブラウザ:Chrome 54.0.2840.71

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ブラウザの文字コードを変更して記事が正しく表示されるコードはありませんか？

Comment: 自己解決しました。
php.iniファイル内の
mbstring.http_inputをautoからUTF-8に変更することで症状が出なくなりました。

Comment: 回答に記載にして解決にして下さい

Answer (score 2, accepted):

既に自己解決されているようですが、mbstring.http_inputはPHP 5.6.0 で非推奨になっているようです。
mbstring.http_inputの編集はdefault_charsetやinput_encodingを編集しても反応しない時の方がいいでしょう。